# Push notifications in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am working with iOS Swift Notifications Module. I'm not getting the Alert/Banner Notification on the device.

I’m able to get notification when the App is open i.e. in Foreground, but not when app in in Background or Terminated.

Following is my code

```
import UIKit

import UserNotifications

import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    //  MARK: - Application Life Cycle
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        FIRApp.configure()

        askNotificationPermission(application)

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.getFirebaseInstaceID(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.firInstanceIDTokenRefresh, object: nil)

        connectToFcm()

        return true
    }

    // MARK:- Push Notification Delegate Methods
    @nonobjc func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }

    func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage) {
        let appdata = remoteMessage.appData as NSDictionary as! [String: AnyObject]
        print(appdata)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }

    //  MARK: - Permissions
    func askNotificationPermission(_ application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { (finished, error) in

            })

            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            FIRMessaging.messaging().remoteMessageDelegate = self

        } else {

            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    //  MARK: - Firebase Connection Methods
    @objc func getFirebaseInstaceID(_ notification: Notification) {

        if isNotNull(FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token() as AnyObject?) {
            let strFirebaseInstanceID = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()! as String
            if !strFirebaseInstanceID.isEmpty {
                print("Firebase Instance ID - \(strFirebaseInstanceID)")
                setString(strValue: strFirebaseInstanceID, forKey: Default.firebaseInstanceID)

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: Notifications.nSendFirebaseID), object: nil)
            } else {
                setString(strValue: "", forKey: Default.firebaseInstanceID)
            }
        } else {
            setString(strValue: "", forKey: Default.firebaseInstanceID)
        }

        connectToFcm()
    }

    func connectToFcm() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Connected to FCM.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the payload that you are sending?

Comment: For what OS you are facing this issue?

Comment: @Karthick I'm facing this issue for iOS 10.1

Comment: Just seen your comment in one of the answers. Could you post a screenshot of a sample message that you're sending using the Notification Console? (*edit out the sensitive details*)

Comment: @AL. Sure, just a minute. I'll update my question with a screenshot

Comment: I have removed two third-party image links from this question, since the owner of the `prntscr.com` account deleted the images. Please always use the image button in the toolbar when wanting to show images, so that link breakage is kept to a minimum and new work is not given to volunteer editors. Thanks!

Comment: @Cœur: I would roll back to rev 5, I think the inclusion of code means that it's not quite vote to close. The OP is playing games with that number of rollbacks, I'd suggest a mod flag too - it counts as edit-warring.

Comment: Dear @VaibhavJhaveri, we've rollback your changes to a version more in phase with community editorial choices. If you have concerns, I would suggest to re-read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) in general or the ["how-to-ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in particular. You may also search on Meta and eventually raise a question on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add this method

```
didReceiveRemoteNotification
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are sending push using FCM, try sending this payload to FCM for push.

```
{
  "to": "<REGISTRATION_TOKEN_HERE>",
  "notification": {
    "body": "Yipeee!!! I nailed it",
    "sound" : "default"
  },
  "data" : ""
}
```

Comment: I'm using Firebase Console to send notification

Comment: I have not tried sending push using console but i do it using googleapi's
Using `post request`, url being `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send` and headers `Authorization:key=yourKey
Content-Type:application/json`

Comment: @TechGeek_iOS `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send` is the GCM endpoint. Although both are still compatible, as much as possible for FCM, use `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`. :)

Comment: Also, I noticed your format -- `"to": "FCM_INSTANCE_ID/GCM_ID_GOES_HERE"`. It doesn't make sense to include the `GCM_ID` there (I'm not even sure what you mean by the `GCM_ID`.

Comment: FCM_INSTANCE_ID is FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token, generated for each device

Comment: Owwww. Right... I thought that you were implying a format. Like a `<token>/<another id here or something>`.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 10.*, you need to give push notification present option in completion handler of `willPresent notification` method list below. Try like this may be helpful.

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {    

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Tried. Didn't help